# Hosted OTA updates with EAS Builds

Tags: react-native, expo

Is it possible to use custom hosted OTA updates with EAS Builds? With Expo CLI, you can use the `--public-url` argument to specify the source of OTA updates. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

late answer, but in case anyone else is looking: you can use the `updates.url` property in app.json

source: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#url